# textures, shadows created in 2.8 look different in 2.82

Tags: blend-files

When opening a 2.8 version file in 2.82, the rug became much darker.  The rug texture and color are from a jpeg file.  Please see attachments for details.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The light and shadow on the left side on the wood wall panels have changed, too.
Is there a way to not have changes like these when opening 2.8 files in version 2.82?  Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to share some screenshots to show the issue? Some other information that might help is the render engine you're using, and if it's a procedural material or based on an image texture.